# NodeJs get size of variable in bytes

Tags: javascript, node.js, readfile

I have a variable 'img' which is an image file that has been loaded via:

```
var img = fs.readFileSync('./tmp.png');
```

How do I determine how many bytes the 'img' variable is?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like `img` is a buffer, you can simply use `img.length`, it will give you the size in octets (byte of 8bits)